# Sendbird v3 SDK iOS init handler not returned

Tags: ios, sendbird, sendbird-ios

When I call init on SBDMain, like:

```
    SBDMain.initWithApplicationId(
      getSendbirdAppID(),
      useCaching: false) {
        print("call back migration")
      } completionHandler: { unsafeError in
        print("call back handler")
      }
```

Neither the completion or migration handlers are called. When I switch `useCaching` to true the completion handler is called.

Is there something else I have to do to get the async caller to come back at the call site?

This is Sendbird iOS SDK v3.1.18

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

The SendbirdChat iOS SDK v4 beta corrects the above behavior and the init closures so far returned as expected.

https://github.com/sendbird/sendbird-chat-sdk-ios/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.9